# Question with mysql characterset

Tags: mysql, database

I notice that there are kinds of charactersets in mysql, for instance:

```
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:
```

So I want to know what is the difference between them? thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

If you want to use different encodings, you have to do some transformations. PHP has some functions for this.